# Static linking on Windows OS

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am using LunarG SDK.I found `VKstatic.1.lib` in the Lib directory.When linking with that lib instead of vulkan-1.lib I am getting the following linker error:

> VKstatic.1.lib(loader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_PathIsRelativeA referenced in function loader_platform_is_path_absolute

Using VS2013 and VS2015,64bit project. 
I see that the [PathIsRelativeA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773660(v=vs.85).aspx) comes from WIndows SDK.I set Linker->System to be `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`,but it doesn't solve the error.
Does static linking require some preprocessor flag?I haven't found any docs on how to link Vulkan statically.

**UPDATE:**

Added `Shlwapi.lib` ,as suggested by  Richard Critten. That solved the linker errors for v120 compiler,but brought more errors for v140.

Comment: Read the library section and add the lib:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773660(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten it solves the issue for VS2013,but throws a bunch of new errors for VS2015.Probably their static lib was built with V120 compiler. :/

Comment: What kind of new errors is that?

Comment: Using prebuild static libs that were created by a different compiler version can be problematic. Even same compiler with different compiler / linker flags can be problematic. Best way around that is to build the library from source.

Comment: For me I had to use "Shlwapi.lib". Lowercase s failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fix the error on Visual Studio 2017 here (in one of the comments):[VKstatic.1.lib not linking](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/6445/webcontrols/WebControls/?fid=35849&df=90&mpp=10&sort=Position&view=Thread&spc=Relaxed&fr=36&prof=True)

You basically just need to link to `cfgmgr32.lib` as well (I did not need to link to `Shlwapi.lib`).